# Edit Magento product view container position

Tags: configurable-product, product-view

I am trying to move the Select size drop-down under quantity box, what file do I need to edit? already tried view.phtml(/products)[image]
Thanks in advance for help

in my add to addtocart.phtml I have only 
`<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>`

I have uploaded  the view.phtml [here](http://pastebin.com/44LqBmYw)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to debug issues like this to to enable **[Magento Template Path Hints](http://www.westwideweb.com/wp/2009/08/04/magento-how-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-and-inline-translation/)**

1. Go to Admin -> System -> Configuration
2. In the top left there is a box named “Current Configuration Scope: “ which has a drop down. From that drop down, choose your store view name.
3. After this go to Advanced -> Developer->Debug And here make Template Path Hints = Yes

[image]

Then reload your page.

I think you will need to more layout block around to achieve this see  [Intro to Layouts - Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts)

Answer (score 1):

I've taken a look at your view.phtml and it appears you can move the Select Size (the options container block) fairly simply by just changing your products setting for the placement of the options container.

If you open your product to edit and go to the Design tab there is an option called 'Display Product Options In', this has 2 choices 'Product Info Column' which is usually above the Quantity and Add to Cart and also 'Block After Info Column' which is usually below the Add to Cart. This will need to be changed for each product.

If you want to change where these containers are placed on the page from these 2 settings you will need to edit your view.phtml file and find the corresponding blocks of code to where you want them, it will either be:

```
                <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>
```

or

```
            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>
```

Depending on which option you have selected as explained above. These are the blocks of code which render the options 'Select Size' block on the page.

Comment: please take a look if you have time over my view file, my template is little different

Comment: please see my updated answer

Comment: for the additional answer you added concerning translation, that's not an answer to your question unfortunately and should be added as a separate question, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the correct way of changing this.

If you look at the template you will see that the product options you want to move are in container2. Container1 and container2 are of type `core/template_facade`. For blocks of this type the position is set via `Mage_Core_Block_Template_Facade::setDataByKeyFromRegistry` which sets the option position based on the "Display Product Options In" setting (Admin/Product/Design) for each product.

I updated all my products by finding the matching attribute_id and EAV table:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE frontend_label = 'Display Product Options In';
```

and then running

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET value = 'container1' WHERE attribute_id = <attribute_id>;
```

To change the default value for new products run:

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET default_value = 'container1' WHERE attribute_code = 'options_container';
```

For a more detailed breakdown on `core/template_facade` [check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11750009/1655741) .